# Display external link using theme settings

Tags: navigation

I'm using theme-settings.php to store links to external pages (like Facebook, Twitter, etc.) and the links aren't storing correctly. In theme-settings.php, I have:

```
function mytheme_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
 $form['mytheme_facebook'] = array(
'#type'          => 'textfield',
'#title'         => t('Facebook Link'),
'#default_value' => theme_get_setting('mytheme_facebook'),
'#description'   => t("Appears in sidebar block."),
```

);

On my Theme Settings page, I enter https://www.facebook.com/ in the "Facebook Link" field. When I hit save, I see that only "www.facebook.com" has been saved in that field.

So, when I call the field on my site, using

```
print theme_get_setting('mytheme_facebook');
```

the link that gets outputted is http://www.myurl.org/www.facebook.com/.

How can I get I get rid of the "myurl" stuff, so I get a working link to Facebook? Oh, and I'm using Drupal 7, if that helps.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is probably applying your default [text format](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#text_format) to your field.

Try adding a `#format` value to the array that matches one of your less strict [input formats](https://www.drupal.org/node/213156).